# my host has no PTR record

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, hostname, reverse-dns, ptr-record

when i check my host i get this

```
host myIP
xx.xxx.xx.103.in-addr.arpa has no PTR record
```

So i dd this to my /var/named/domainname.com.db

```
myHostname. IN A  myIP
xx.xxx.xx.103.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR myHostname.
```

I restart BIND DNS Server

but when i check my domainname on http://www.intodns.com

```
Reverse MX A records (PTR)  ERROR: No reverse DNS (PTR) entries. The problem MX records are:
xx.xxx.xx.103.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected
You should contact your ISP and ask him to add a PTR record for your ips
```

So i tried also to do this

```
echo -e "update add xx.xxx.xx.103.in-addr.arpa 3600 ptr myHostname.\nsend" | nsupdate
; Communication with server failed: timed out
```

So what's the correct way to resolve this issue please

Comment: You should contact your ISP as you were already advised to do.

Comment: To put things in perspective, this is equivalent to painting "Bob's Residence" on the side of your house and expecting the city to update their official address registry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RDNS entry needs to be added in to the authoritative RDNS zone for your IP block. Note that an RDNS zone is not your domain name's DNS zone.

Whoever owns your IP block will be able to do this for you, which will be the ISP who has allocated the IP address to you.

Alternately if you have your own IP block allocated to you by the relevant authority for your region (eg. ARIN / APNIC etc.), create an RDNS zone for your allocated subnets and add in the RDNS entries. You will also need to make sure that the DNS server delegation for your IP block points to your DNS servers.